# Swift killed app fetch data in location service?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to fetch data when app killed. But I think I can not fetch data if app is killed.

Location update service is running when app killed. Can I fetch my data in location service and update local db?

Or any way to get data when app is killed? Just I want to request some apis, getting data from them and insert local db.

Comment: you can run a long running task for few minutes when app is killed. But cannot run a permanent service. If you can tell your exact requirement. Then we might find a solution for you :)

Comment: I am creating news app and I am getting data from api. My news db should be up to date and I do not want to waste time to load data when app is opening. I want to update db every 30 min after app killed.

Comment: most feasible solution for your scenario is to use Background App Refresh. Read this, you will get a better understanding. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You set `background task` but limited time.

It depends on device battery

Be sure opened `Location Updates` in `Capabilities`

You can check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time) for background task

**Example code:**

```
final class LocationManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = LocationManager()

    private var backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func startMonitoring() {
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        print("LocationManager didStartMonitoringFor")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        postLocation(location: locations.first)
    }
}

extension LocationManager {

    private func postLocation(location: CLLocation?) {
        guard let location = location else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {

            backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "locationTaskName", expirationHandler: {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
                self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
            })

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.postRequest(location: location) { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
                    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
                }
            }
        } else {
            postRequest(location: location)
        }

    }

    private func postRequest(location: CLLocation, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        // TODO Request
        //service.sendLocation
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, but ***no***. Since your app is closed, you can not get any data, or do any other stuff. You can do all stuff when app is open with some math.

Comment: For example: you have variable called "money", and your income in second is 3 dollars. Total second * income (3) = earned money

Comment: so how is the app working when they killed? There are many apps in store and they can sent notification after refresh the data

Comment: i think the only things, that can work when app is killed are notifications